# LINQ Problem with Distinct count

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, distinct

Trying to understand what's wrong, but i really cant do it. So:

```
return dc.dictionaries.Select(
       d => new AdminDictionaryViewModel 
       { dictionary = d,
         WordQuantity = dc.interpretations.Where(
                        i => i.iddictionary == d.iddictionary).Count() });
```

This works fine, but if i change to:

```
return dc.dictionaries.Select(
       d => new AdminDictionaryViewModel
       { dictionary = d,
         WordQuantity = dc.interpretations.Where(
                        i => i.iddictionary == d.iddictionary)
                       .Distinct(new WordsInDictionaryDistinct()).Count() });
```

And my class is:

```
public class WordsInDictionaryDistinct : IEqualityComparer<interpretation>
{
    public bool Equals(interpretation x, interpretation y)
    {
        return x.idword.Equals(y.idword) && y.idword.Equals(x.idword);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(interpretation obj)
    {
        return obj.idword.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

I have:

```
dictionary table

iddictionary | dictionary_name
```

---

```
word table

idword | word_name
```

---

```
interpretation table

idinterpretation | iddictionary | idword
```

---

And i need to have just distinct idword in each of dictionary, bcz if i return in my first query, there could be about 10 words with idword = 15, but this is one word, not 15:

interpretation table

```
idinterpretation | iddictionary | idword | meaning
1                   1              1115     hello
2                   1              1115     hi
3                   1              1115     hi, bro
4                   1              1116     
5                   1              1118     good bye
6                   1              1118     bye-bye
7                   2
8                   2
```

After my second query, i hope i'll get {d = 1, WordQuantity = 3}, but there is

**Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Distinct'.**

I've tried

`.ToList<interpretation>().Distinct(new WordsInDictionaryDistinct()).Count()`

but still the same error.

Really, dont know what to do :(

Comment: Does it work if you throw in an `AsEnumerable()` call before `Distinct()` instead?

Comment: No, still the same error. Now, i think, maybe it could be done with GroupBy idword

Comment: Is dc.interpretations an `IEnumerable<interpretation>`?

Comment: public System.Data.Linq.Table<interpretation> interpretations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `IEqualityComparer` can not be translated to SQL.

Try replacing

```
.Distinct(new WordsInDictionaryDistinct())
```

with

```
.Select(x => x.idword).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be better off changing your query to group instead of the way it is now, you will probably get better performance, too.

```
return (from d in dc.dictionaries
        join i in dc.interpretations on d.iddictionary == i.iddictionary
        group i by d into g
        select AdminDictionaryViewModel()
        {
            dictionary = g.Key,
            WorkQuantity = g.Distinct(o => o.idword).Count()
        });
```